# How much time does top command consider while finding CPU usage percentage?

Tags: cpu-usage, top

Top gives me an output like:

```
%Cpu(s):  4.7 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.9 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

if my CPU has spent 4.7% of its time on user processes, how much of time history has it considered before coming up with such a result?

Comment: Search for "how does linux top work" gives the following as the top (pun intended) result [where does top gets real-time data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827077/where-does-top-gets-real-time-data)

Comment: @DavidPostill, right. So is it based on idle and non-idle times read ever since the CPU started? The link doesn't mention that, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

From [where does top gets real-time data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831156/3536342), answer by bdonlan:

> As documented in [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), in the file `/proc/(pid)/stat` you have the
>   fields:
>
> `utime %lu`
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK). This includes
>   guest time, guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below),
>   so that applications that are not aware of the guest time field do not
>   lose that time from their calculations.
>
> `stime %lu`
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

Comment: does this mean that these values are measured since when the process/CPU started?